# Carregar itens restantes do array

Tags: php

Olá,

Recebo via $_POST o ID de 1 ou mais produtos, que já estão salvos na tabela 'produtos', que contém mais dados salvos junto na tabela (ipi,icms) gostaria de pegar esses dados restantes de cada produto através do ID de cada produto recebido pelo POST e depois salvar através de um INSERT que já tenho funcionando tudo aqui embaixo (só falta pegar os campos restantes da tabela 'produto' de cada produto pelo ID dele recebido no array).

```
//POST em array que recebo

$valor_unitario = $_POST['valorunitario'];
$nome-produto= $_POST['nome_produto'];
$quant_produto = $_POST['quant_produto'];
$subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
$id_produto = $_POST['id_produto'];


//AQUI INSERE OS ARRAYS NO BANCO DE DADOS, RECEBE OS PRODUTOS ADICIONADOS VIA POST (AQUI QUERO SALVAR O RESTANTE DOS CAMPOS DO PRODUTO ATRAVÉS DO ID DELES.
$i=0;
$sql= "INSERT INTO `log_nfe_produtos` (`NOME_PRODUTO`, `VALOR_UNITARIO`, `QUANT_PRODUTO`, `SUBTOTAL`, `ID_EMPRESA`,`ID_NF`) VALUES ";

foreach($nome_produto as $p){

$sql=$sql."('$p','$valor_unitario[$i]','$quant_produto[$i]','$subtotal[$i]','1','$cod_pedido[$i]'),";

$i++;

}

$sqlFinal = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-1);

$sqlFinal2 = $conn->prepare("$sqlFinal");

$sqlFinal2->execute();
```

Comment: Teria que fazer um select na tabela produtos e pegar os valores que deseja.

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta um exemplo de dados que você recebe no POST e também como é a estrutura da tabela de produtos. Provavelmente você terá que fazer um `INSERT SELECT` ao invés de um `INSERT VALUES` e se você tem o ID do produto não precisa enviar para o POST a descrição do produto.

Comment: Recebo os dados como ID, NOME, VALOR, gostaria de receber outros como ICMS, COFINS....

Comment: @RafaelWeber , amigo, você saberia como me ajudar a implementar isso,poderia dar um exemplo ?